# SiteData.GetSite not returning URL details

Tags: xml, web-services, sharepoint

I use following web service to get sites in a SharePoint server.

> **Web Service:** SiteData
>
> **Web Reference:** http:///_vti_bin/SiteData.asmx

```
POST /_vti_bin/sitedata.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: sharepoint
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetSite"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetSite xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

As per the definition it should return a response as below;

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetSiteResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <GetSiteResult>unsignedInt</GetSiteResult>
      <sSiteMetadata>
        <LastModified>dateTime</LastModified>
        <LastModifiedForceRecrawl>dateTime</LastModifiedForceRecrawl>
        <SmallSite>boolean</SmallSite>
        <PortalUrl>string</PortalUrl>
        <UserProfileGUID>string</UserProfileGUID>
        <ValidSecurityInfo>boolean</ValidSecurityInfo>
      </sSiteMetadata>
      <vWebs>
        <_sWebWithTime>
          <Url>string</Url>
          <LastModified>dateTime</LastModified>
        </_sWebWithTime>
        <_sWebWithTime>
          <Url>string</Url>
          <LastModified>dateTime</LastModified>
        </_sWebWithTime>
      </vWebs>
      <strUsers>string</strUsers>
      <strGroups>string</strGroups>
      <vGroups>
        <string>string</string>
        <string>string</string>
      </vGroups>
    </GetSiteResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But I get following type of response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetSiteResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <GetSiteResult>unsignedInt</GetSiteResult>
            <sSiteMetadata>
                <LastModified>dateTime</LastModified>
                <LastModifiedForceRecrawl>dateTime</LastModifiedForceRecrawl>
                <SmallSite>boolean</SmallSite>
                <PortalUrl />
                <ValidSecurityInfo>boolean</ValidSecurityInfo>
            </sSiteMetadata>
            <strGroups>string</strGroups>
            <vGroups>
                <string>string</string>
                <string>string</string>
            </vGroups>
        </GetSiteResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

In this following response is missing;

```
<vWebs>
        <_sWebWithTime>
          <Url>string</Url>
          <LastModified>dateTime</LastModified>
        </_sWebWithTime>
        <_sWebWithTime>
          <Url>string</Url>
          <LastModified>dateTime</LastModified>
        </_sWebWithTime>
      </vWebs>
```

By the above xml I extract the url's. Since its not returning the above xml, available sites are shown as not exist.

What am I doing wrong? How to get the vWebs tags in my response?

**EDIT:**
Our SharePoint server is a different PC. I'm added as a user. When I'm in the farm administrators group this happens. If my account is deleted from farm administrators then this returns the vWebs. All users added to the farm experience this. Once they are removed then this works fine.